# Unable to access a customized header in CORS environment using spring mvc and $http

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, cors

I have done an extensive search for the mentioned issue, but unable to find a workable solution.
Kindly have a look on some imp codes and suggest.

```
// My factory method that returns a promise 
contactBackend : function(requestedMethod, requestedUrl,
                        requestedData) {
                    return $http({
                        method : requestedMethod,
                        url : backend + requestedUrl,
                        data : requestedData
                    });
                }

//Actual Login method that calls the 
loginC.validateLogin = function() {
                welcomeMFactory.contactBackend("POST", "/rs/login",
                        loginC.user).then(
                        function(success) {
                            var msg = success.data.loginMsg;
                            if (msg == "login.valid") {
                                alert(JSON.stringify(success));
                                welcomeMFactory.moveToWidget("/home");
                            } else {
                                loginC.error = welcomeMFactory.printMsg(
                                        true, msg);
                            }
                        },
                        function(error) {
                            loginC.error = welcomeMFactory.printMsg(true,
                                    "Unable to reach backend for login");
                        });
            }
```

// SpringController.xml

```
<mvc:cors>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**" allowed-origins="http://localhost:8080"
        allowed-headers="content-type,authentication" exposed-headers="content-type,authentication" />
</mvc:cors>
```

//Login Controller

```
@Autowired
private LoginRespI response;

@Autowired
private ProxyHandler proxyHandler;

@Autowired
private LoginServiceImpl loginServiceImpl;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public LoginRespB authenticateUserLogin(@RequestBody LoginReqB request, HttpServletResponse resp) {

    LoginDTO loginDTO = loginServiceImpl.validateLoginService(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword());
    if (loginDTO != null) {
        response.setLoginMsg("login.valid");
    } else {
        response.setLoginMsg("login.invalid");
    }

    Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject("ABCDE");
    claims.put("ID", "12345");
    String toke = Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "ABCDE").compact();
    resp.setHeader("Authentication", "Bearer: " + toke);

    return (LoginRespB) (proxyHandler.getTargetObject(response));
}
```

[OPTIONS req/resp headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvbaX.png)

[Login req/resp headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti5oZ.png)

Comment: Still unable to solve this... Any suggestions..?

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your code ,it will allow cros domain request

```
package org.codingpedia.demo.rest.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

public class CORSResponseFilter
implements ContainerResponseFilter {

public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {

    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://podcastpedia.org"); //allows CORS requests only coming from podcastpedia.org       
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");          
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia");
}

}
```

Comment: thanks for the input..but kindly clarify...what's wrong with my code....?